# "Invisible" states in automata with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows, automata

I am new to Tikz and drawing things with LaTex, so I have a question.
This is the code for my tikz drawing

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
    \node[state] (q_0) {$0$};
    \node[state] (q_1) [right=of q_0] {$1$};
    \node[state] (q_2) [right=of q_1] {$2$};
    \node[rectangle] (q_dots) [right=of q_2] {$\cdots$}; 
    \node[state] (q_3) [right=of q_dots] {{\footnotesize $j-1$}};    
    \node[state] (q_4) [right=of q_3] {$j$};
    \node        (q_5) [right=of q_4] {$\cdots$};

    \path[->]
    (q_0) edge [bend left] node {$\lambda_0$} (q_1)
    (q_1) edge [bend left] node {$\mu_1$} (q_0)
    (q_1) edge [bend left] node {$\lambda_1$} (q_2)
    (q_2) edge [bend left] node {$\mu_2$} (q_1)
    (q_2) edge [bend left] node {$\lambda_2$} (q_dots)
    (q_dots) edge [bend left] node {$\mu_3$} (q_2)
    (q_dots) edge [bend left] node {$\lambda_{j-2}$} (q_3)
    (q_3) edge [bend left] node {$\mu_{j-1}$} (q_dots) 
    (q_3) edge [bend left] node {$\lambda_{j-1}$} (q_4)
    (q_4) edge [bend left] node {$\mu_j$} (q_3)
    (q_4) edge [bend left] node {$\lambda_{j}$} (q_5)
    (q_5) edge [bend left] node {$\mu_{j+1}$} (q_4) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The result I am getting is fine, besides the fact that the text after the "..." is not in the middle of the arrows.

Apart from that I want to create another "invisible" state in the end of my drawing, and instead of the "..." to have a node that is not showing up, so that my arrows look like this while they are pointing to nowhere.

Thank you very much in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you replace

```
\node[rectangle] (q_dots) [right=of q_2] {$\cdots$};
```

with

```
\node[state, draw=none] (q_dots) [right=of q_2] {$\cdots$};
```

it works.

However, I'm not sure about your second point. You want the last dots to be actually an invisible node?

Comment: Yes, I want the arrows to point that way towards nothing (empty space).

Comment: `\node (q_5) [right=of q_4] {\phantom{$\cdots$}};`

Comment: @Maggie Sorry I was not here. The best way is like Maarten said, using `\phantom{}`, which basically makes the text invisible but still "writes" it, so that it takes the same space. If you left the node empty, this could make the scheme inconsistent depending on whether you set the nodes size or not.

Comment: Thank you very very much for both your answers, they solved my problem and I learnt new things! :)